# How to invoke a plugin in Phonegap not in Cordova?

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am new to Phonegap. I build the .apk through Adobe Phonegap. I need a alarm plugin with background mode. I can able to install the plugin but i don't know how to use it.

I don't know to configure config.xml and invoke in index.html.

I have use the plugin is https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications/

Can you please explain me in detail by step by step method.

Comment: https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications/tree/example here s an example have you checked that one?

Comment: I have download the code and make the apk through adobe phonegap and installed in my device but its not working?